# What is wrong with my Model and Interface? (Java Spring Boot webapp)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, backend, spring-tool-suite

I have an error during running that says (with full directories omitted for brevity:

> Error creating bean with name 'idea_Service' defined in file
>   [...com\vincentsnow\brightideas\services\Idea_Service.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'idea_Repository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Object

and another:

> Error creating bean with name 'idea_Repository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

I haven't used these lowercase names anywhere. I can't make sense of this message...I'm guessing it's trying to compile but changing the filenames for some reason. No errors are caught by STS in my files. Here they are:

Idea_Service.java (service)

```
    package com.vincentsnow.brightideas.services;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models.Idea;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models.User;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.repositories.Idea_Repository;

@Service
public class Idea_Service {
    private Idea_Repository ideaRepository;
    public Idea_Service(Idea_Repository ideaRepository){
        this.ideaRepository = ideaRepository;
    }

    public List<Idea> allIdeas(){
        return ideaRepository.findAllIdeas();
    }

    public void createUser(String idea, User posted_by){
        ideaRepository.save(idea, posted_by);
    }

    public Idea oneIdea(Long id) {
        return ideaRepository.getSingleIdeaWhereId(id);
    }

    public List<Idea> likesof(Long id){
        return ideaRepository.getLikesOfIdea(id);
    }
}
```

Idea.java (model)

```
package com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models.User;

@Entity
public class Idea {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column
        @Size(min=3, max=5000)
        private String idea;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="idea_id")
        private User posted_by;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(
            name = "likes", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idea_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
            )
            private List<Idea> likes;


}
```

Idea_Repository.java (repository)

```
package com.vincentsnow.brightideas.repositories;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models.Idea;
import com.vincentsnow.brightideas.models.User;

@Repository
public interface Idea_Repository extends CrudRepository {

    @Query("SELECT a FROM ideas a")
    List<Idea> findAllIdeas();

    @Query(value="INSERT INTO ideas (idea, posted_by) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)", nativeQuery=true)
    Idea save(String idea, User posted_by);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM ideas a WHERE id=?1")
    Idea getSingleIdeaWhereId(Long id);

    @Query(value="SELECT likes WHERE idea_id = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Idea> getLikesOfIdea(Long id); 

}
```

What is wrong with them? What does this error mean? What is STS trying to do?

Comment: Please show persistence.xml file

Comment: you appear to have pasted Idea.java under Idea_Service.java

Comment: Ah, so I have! Edited, thank you.

Comment: I do not have any persistence.xml file. Do you mean the pom.xml?

Comment: You don't have a persistence.xml because you don't yet need one: Spring Boot looks after that for you, providing sensible defaults, inferring things from annotations and jars on the classpath, etc.

Comment: You're using raw types. Pay attention to your IDE's warnings about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CrudRepository` takes two formal parameters, being the type that it manages and the type of that type's ID. Since you haven't provided these parameters, they are effectively `Object` and `Object`: the error message is pointing out that `Object` isn't a manageable object (it's not annotated with `@Entity`). You need to tell Spring Data that the class your repository is actually trying to manage is `Idea`. Try:

```
public interface Idea_Repository extends CrudRepository<Idea, Long> {
    // ..
}
```

Also, you don't need `findAllIdeas`, `save` or `getSingleIdeaWhereId`; equivalent methods are provided by Spring Data JPA for free.